# IE DOMContentLoaded documentElement.doScroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Is there any reason why [DOMContentLoaded trick for IE by Diego Perini](http://javascript.nwbox.com/IEContentLoaded/) is implemented only when window is not in iframe in popular JS Libraries?

jQuery:

```
//If IE and not a frame continually check to see if the document is ready

  var toplevel = false;

  try {
    toplevel = window.frameElement == null;
  } catch(e) {}

  if ( document.documentElement.doScroll && toplevel ) {
    doScrollCheck();
  }
```

Prototype:

```
document.observe('readystatechange', checkReadyState);
if (window == top)
  timer = pollDoScroll.defer();
```

Both of them checks is window is equal to top and if it is the `document.documentElement.doScroll('left');` is used to check ready state. 
But why not to use it when `window != top`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This bug report](http://yuilibrary.com/projects/yui2/ticket/2008289) for YUI library states that doScroll in framed document doesn't work the same way as when run on top level (doesn't throw errors when document isn't ready).

Comment: I think this is the best answer I can get in this subject. Thanks!